# Change paragraph object for rendering

Tags: 8, hooks, paragraphs

I have a paragraph type with a node ref field that, if you leave it empty, is supposed to show a random node using some defined logic.

I have the code to do the query and get the node, and ideally I'd want to put it on the paragraph object in some pre-render hook so that the paragraph can render normally using its usual config. Something like this (warning: pseudo-codish):

```
function mymodule_paragraph_view($build, $paragraph, $display, $view_mode) {
  if (!is_my_paragraph_type($paragraph)) return;

  if (!$paragraph->field_mynoderef->isEmpty()) return;

  $node = getRandomNode();
  $paragraph->set('field_mynoderef', $node);
}
```

This is setting the value correctly, but it seems it's too late in the render process for it to affect the rendered output (i.e. it doesn't actually show the node). I've also tried doing that on the `$build['#paragraph']` object, which contains the same paragraph, with similar results. **How can I make this work?**

BONUS: How to make it so it caches the output using a time-based configuration (e.g. expire after 60 seconds, so every minute it will show a different node and it won't run the query logic on every request).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the loaded node into a renderable array, and add it to the `$build` array.

```
$node = getRandomNode();

$entity_type = $node->getEntityTypeId();
$view_mode = 'teaser';
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
$build['field_mynoderef'] = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);
```

Your question on caching is not related to this issue and should be separated into a separate question. Drupal Answers is a Q&A site with the format of one question to one answer, and adding the answer to that question would dilute this topic.

Comment: What if I want to reuse the paragraph display config? (maybe I'm asking for too much, but it seems like it should be possible) This is why I wanted to modify the paragraph object itself and not play with render arrays for the actual node. The idea is to be able to forget about this code, in case the paragraph display config ever changes (e.g. the view mode for the node).

Comment: Also, is hook_paragraph_view right for this? Because there's also hook_paragraph_view_alter, and of course hook_preprocess_paragraph (the last of which I think is definitely too late in the process).

Comment: I'd use `hook_paragraph_view_alter()` for this. And you should create a new view mode for this display, and assign the fields to that view mode. Then use that view mode instead of 'teaser', and you won't have to worry about anyone changing display, as it will only be used for this view.